# Run A For Loop on a Data Frame

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
draftclasses
```

```
Name Yards TDs Class
Joe Smith 333.3 34 2017
Carson Mathers 386.2 22 2021
Bo Someome 345.2 22 2022
Im Notgood 170.99 7 2017
```

What I would like to do is get all of the `Yards` subset for each value in the `Class` column. I know to filter out a subset of the data frame:

`year2021 = draftclass[!is.na(draftclasses$Yards) & draftclasses$Class == 2022,]`

I am also aware I would use a for loop but don't know how to design it. I've read around online a bit but I am still unsure how to run a loop to get this input for each year in the `Class` column.

Ideally I would like each year in `Class` to label a object with a string of all of the yards pertaining to a class like so:

```
> year2017
[1] "333.3" "170.99"
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: From your second code block, it appears that your numbers are instead strings, is that true?

Comment: No, the numbers are in a column in a data frame, and I would like to make a string subset for each value in the Class column and loop it without doing it through multiple steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of `split` we can `split` the `Yards` for each `Class`.

```
result <- split(draftclasses$Yards, draftclasses$Class)
```

This returns a list in `result`, if you want a separate vector for each `Class`, you can name the list and use `list2env`.

```
names(result) <- paste0('year', names(result))
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)

year2017
#[1] 333.30 170.99

year2021
#[1] 386.2

year2022
#[1] 345.2
```